# Ruby's Faraday - Send optional parameters in get method

Tags: ruby, faraday

I have an endpoint with multiple optional parameters.

```
def get_customers(params=nil)
   if params.nil?
      customer_url = "#{@url}/customers"
      # call api
      response = connection.get(customer_url)
   else
     # I do not know how to write this part
   end   
end
```

Could you please help me in order to write a call to and endpoint with optional parameters. The params argument is a hash (key, pair value). The query can have 8 parameters. I do not know how to concatenate the params to the url. I am stack in this section. I am a rookie at ruby and faraday.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to concatenate params with the url on your own. Faraday can accept a hash of params (or nil). You can pass them to the get method like so:

```rb
response = connection.get(customer_url, params)
```

Have into the "*GET, HEAD, DELETE, TRACE*" section of [the documentation](https://lostisland.github.io/faraday/usage/) for more examples.

Side note: you don't event have to concatenate url and the path. You can pass them as separate arguments.